# Prevent EF Core from dropping tables in DB

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ef-code-first

I created a new project in VS 2017 with template authentication by individual accounts. So I had initial migration with code generating required tables for storing account info. The problem is that once the migration done, with subsequent migrations those created tables are viewed as unwanted and suggested to drop every new migration, because there aren't their POCO models in project. So how can I to 'hide' them from from EF Core migration, is there any convenient way, except editing every migration manually?

Comment: Remove these classes from DBContext

Answer (score 0):

My error was creating custom `DbContext` inherited not from `IdentityDbContext`, but from `DbContext`, so all those tables were like "foreign".